# How to test server-sent-events with REST-Assured?

Tags: rest-assured, server-sent-events

How can I test a sever sent events endpoint with REST-Assured?
I have tried the following, but the test doesn't terminate:

```kotlin
        val stream = RestAssured.given()
                .contentType(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
                .get("/status/stream").asInputStream()

        myService.publish(SomeEvent())
        val line = stream.reader().readText()

        stream.close()
        assertEquals("my-event", line)
```

myService.publish() pushes an object as the data payload to the SSE stream, which is validated by another test.
The assertion here is only exemplary. The problem is how to receive data from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can read SSE urls with javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSource.